# Python, checking the string in umber and slash /

Tags: python

I'm working on the string checking of the Application no. which contain the format #####/#### (ex: 00012/2017).

What i have done with the string number checking already as follow:

```
    if len(application_no) != 10:
        return False

    a = application_no[0:5]

    if not a.isdigit():
        return False

    b = application_no[7:10]

    if not b.isdigit():
        return False
```

So now, I want to check the string contain only slash / only. Anyone can help me on this please share.

Thank you.

Comment: `if '/' in application_no`? If you want to check if the slash is in `application_no`, you can use `in`. Else it should be something like `application_no[6] == '/'`

Comment: I would initially split('/') and check each token

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check that the string matches the `^\d{5}/\d{4}$` regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> application_pattern = re.compile("^\d{5}/\d{4}$")
>>> application_pattern.match("00012/2017")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ff67680f440>
>>> application_pattern.match("00012/2a17")
>>> application_pattern.match("00012a2017")
```

The 2 last ones return `None` because the strings don't have the required format.

`^\d{5}/\d{4}$` means :

- beginning of string
- 5 digits
- one slash
- 4 digits
- end of string

If you're sure that the last 4 digits are years after 2000, you could use `^\d{5}/20\d{2}$`

Answer (score 0):

In place of all those string slicing and condition checking you can use regular expression to validate the application no. Regular expression matches a given string against a pattern. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html)

```
import re

match = re.match(r'^\d{5}/\d{4}$', '00012/2017')
if match:
  # do_something
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try
Method 1 :

```
>>> s = "00012/2017"
>>> "/" in s
True
>>> s.count("/")
1
>>> s.find("/")
5
```

Method 2:

```
>>> s = "00012/2017"
>>> s[5] == "/"
True
```

Method 3: Reqular Expression:

```
^\d{5}/\d{4}$
```

It means starts with digit, First 5 digits then "/" and after that 4 digits.

Comment: @downvoter : Can yo please justify the reason behind downvote?